# date fns user availability

Tags: react-native, date-fns

Any thoughts on how to get timeslots considering availability and bookings that have been made on the selected day? Get all bookings for that day and course and

```
var timeslots = [];

  // what is already reserved
  var bookings = [
   { id: '1', startDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 11, 0),  endDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 12, 0) },
    { id: '2', startDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 14, 0),  endDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 15, 0) }
  ];

  // what is indicated as free time
  var availability = [
    { id: '1', startDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 9, 0),  endDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 13, 0) },
    { id: '2', startDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 14, 0),  endDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 18, 0) },
  ];

// selected course with duration
  var courses = [
    { id: '1', duration: 30, title: 'Hello 30' }, 
    { id: '2', duration: 45, title: 'Hello 45' }, 
    { id: '3', duration: 60, title: 'Hello 60' }, 
    { id: '4', duration: 90, title: 'Hello 90' }
  ];

  while (isBefore(availability[0].startDate, availability[0].endDate)) {
    let currentStartDate = availability[0].startDate;
    availability[0].startDate = roundToNearestMinutes(addMinutes(availability[0].startDate, courses[0].duration), { nearestTo: 30 });
    timeslots.push(format(currentStartDate, 'p') + ' - ' + format(availability[0].startDate, 'p'));
  }
```

**VIEW**

```
// simple output to see timeslots
{timeslots.map((item) => 
  <Text>{item}</Text>
)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by slightly updating the logic and using the `areIntervalsOverlapping` of date-fns. The draft working solution is below.

```
  var timeslots = [];

  var bookings = [
    { id: '1', startDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 11, 0),  endDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 12, 0) },
    { id: '2', startDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 14, 0),  endDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 15, 0) }
  ];

  var availabilities = [
    { id: '1', startDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 9, 0),  endDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 13, 0) },
    { id: '2', startDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 14, 0),  endDate: new Date(2022, 7, 15, 18, 0) }
  ];

  var courses = [
    { id: '1', duration: 30, title: 'Hello 30' }, 
    { id: '2', duration: 45, title: 'Hello 45' }, 
    { id: '3', duration: 60, title: 'Hello 60' }, 
    { id: '4', duration: 90, title: 'Hello 90' }
  ];

  let SELECTED_COURSE = courses[1];

  for (let availability of availabilities) {
    while (isBefore(availability.startDate, availability.endDate)) {
      let currentStartDate = availability.startDate;
      availability.startDate = roundToNearestMinutes(addMinutes(availability.startDate, SELECTED_COURSE.duration), { nearestTo: 30 });

      timeslots.push(
        {
          startDate: currentStartDate,
          endDate: availability.startDate,
          formattedStartDate: format(currentStartDate, 'p'),
          formattedEndDate: format(availability.startDate, 'p')
        }
      );
    }
  }

  for (let booking of bookings) {
    for (var j = 0; j < timeslots.length; j++) {
      let isOverlapping = areIntervalsOverlapping({ start: booking.startDate, end: booking.endDate }, { start: timeslots[j].startDate, end: timeslots[j].endDate });
      
      if (isOverlapping) {
        timeslots.splice(j, 1);
      }
    }
  }
```